# Posting question on chat

Tags: support, etiquette, chat

Is it okay to post any asked question link in mathematics chat room to get attention, and get answer soon? I was thinking if I had did some thing wrong by posting in chat room to get answer.

Comment: Also, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/main-chatroom-etiquette-rules

Comment: This seems to be (to some extent) related to the [previous post by the same OP](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25124/no-response-to-question) (now deleted). So I will repost the link given there in comments, since it is, in my opinion, at least partially relevant for this question: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3478)

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of [Is it good, if I insert my problem on public chat to get more attention?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22230) Or, if not duplicate, then at least very close to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is in general not okay to do this. The rule of thumb to decide such things is to imagine what would happen if everybody did that. The chat room would be completely swamped. In addition users looking for questions to answer usually look on the main site anyway and not in chat.

This does not mean that it is never alright. But as a rule, please, don't do this.